# Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted on HTTPS

Tags: linux, unix, server

I have hosted my Django application on my Linux server. The first time it works fine by using HTTP but after allowing HTTPS it gives me an error **Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.** What should I need to add to my server setting?

I expect to have somebody who will help me to fix this error.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to list all trusted origins using CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#csrf-trusted-origins